# Section mechanism in Coq. Forbid omitting of hypotheses from context

Tags: coq

I need more primitive mechanism of generalization in sections.
For example,

```
Section sec.
Context (n:nat).
Definition Q:=bool.
End sec.
Check Q.
```

I will obtain Q : Set, but I need Q:nat->Set.

I've tried Context, Hypotheses, Variables. It doesn't work.
How to obtain such behavior?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is not a thing you can do with `Definition ... :=`  However, you can use `Proof using`:

```
Section sec.
Context (n:nat).
Definition Q : Set.
Proof using n.
  exact bool.
Defined.
End sec.
Check Q.
```